# python scripts creating csv file, with Archive check box is checked. How to create a csv file not archive?

Tags: python

I am facing a strange problem
Whenever my python scripts are creating any csv file, it is making them "Archive".
I mean in properties, Archive check box is checked. 
Because of which it can't be read in later part of same script .
How can i create a csv file not archive?
Please help me resolve this problem.

Comment: Please support your question with a relevant code snippet and a screen shot of where you are actually observing "Archive" selected

Comment: If you mean the Windows "Archive" attribute, then you're incorrect.  Not only does it not mean what you think it means, that attribute cannot impact your ability to read the file, immediately or later.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running a Windows OS? If yes, then this is not a problem with the Python CSV library. As about the error encountered while reading the CSV; you may want to re-check your python code for any flaws.

The Archive checkbox is actually an attribute of the file on Windows systems that indicates that the file needs to be backed up. Right click on any other file and you should see "Archive" checked.

Here are a couple of links that would give you more information

[MSDN Technet discussion on File Attributes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090219-00/?p=19093)

[Wikipedia article on Archive bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_bit)